# Avoid numbers being always rounded while using format

Tags: excel, vba, format

It's quite a basic problem but I can't seems to use the right format so that the numbers in my listbox aren't automatically rounded

I wanted to have a column showing prices but it's always rounded to the unit before the coma. I'm currently using this code

```
ListBox.List(lngIndex, 3) = (Format(ListBox.List(lngIndex, 3), "0.00€;0.00€"))
```

And instead of 85,72 I get 85.

Comment: Is it possible that the column width is too small?

Comment: Nope, it can show up to 4 numbers after the coma while I never use more than 2

Comment: How do you know? I can decrease the column width that it only shows two numbers and the remaining digits are just cut off.

Comment: I simply tried it, and I know every entry so i'm certain about what's inside

Comment: I also tried it and I was able to display it with no values after the coma although the value itself was still 85,72. I think the OP has to clarify unless you are the OP

Comment: Just another remark: What do you see in the immediate window when you add the line `debug.print ListBox.List(lngIndex, 3)` just after the line you posted.

Comment: Is your data 85,72 or 85.72?

Comment: My data is 85,72

Comment: The debug.print give me 85,00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a miss configuration of an SQL database where the list took her source. A column wasn't configured as Decimal. Quite embarassing

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the source of your `Format()` function is a **string**: `ListBox.List(lngIndex, 3)`, while `Format` expects a Number or Date. There must be some implicit conversion that loses the decimals.
If you type `print Format(0.856, "0.00€;0.00€")` in the debug window it works fine.

Comment: If I enter Format("85,72", "0.00€;0.00€") in the debug window it also works quite well even if it's entered as a string

Comment: on my pc, `print Format("85,72", "0.00€;0.00€")` returns 8572.00€, which is *not* what is expected. `"85.72"` (with a decimal dot) is working.

Comment: It may have something to do with my localization, cause I use Excel in French.